# Anylogic Resource Pool Requests Queue not clearing

Tags: anylogic

I have a very simple model with a service block that needs a resource set of two resource pools, one of each.

[image]

In addition to that, one of the two resource pools has a request choice condition. Both resource pools have a capacity of 1.

[image]

`variable` has an initial value of false.

When I run the model, and agents arrive, they will not be processed due to the condition. Now if I change the condition from false to true on runtime, the agents remain stuck in the service block's queue. It's like the condition is evaluated on agent arrival and is not checked again once the condition updates and what's worse is it's like the resource is reserved and not used by the agents coming later, after the condition is changed from false to true.

[image]

Is this by design? And how can this be resolved?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just heard back from AnyLogic.
They confirmed this is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the most annoying things when using resources in AnyLogic, so the solution is to be smart in using the function

```
service.recalculateResourceChoiceConditions()
```

In your case, when the variable value changes, you need to immediately after that run this method.

When you have many agents, doing this is slow, so you just need to do it as efficiently as possible

It is similar with anything that requires conditionals in AnyLogic, such as an event triggered by condition or transition triggered by condition. There's never a guarantee that you will trigger the condition, and for that reason you always have to take action manually.

If it wasn't like this, AnyLogic would be super slow always, so i guess yes it is by design

Comment: I appreciate the answer, Felipe, thank you!
My question may not have been perfectly clear. The situation is a bit more confusing than that. First, it's not the service that is using a "Customized Resource Choice", it's the resource pool (check 2nd image in question) and it doesn't have an equivalent function of recalculating that condition. Second, it's not just that it's ignoring the resource once the condition is true, it is actually reserving the other resource, from the other resource pool, although they are a set (same thing happens when I use a seize block with "seize all at once".).

Comment: Also, the reason I am using the resource pool's condition and not the service's is because there are multiple conditions on different resource types for the same service.

Comment: it doesn't matter where the condition is located, you can still do the service method and it will work... On the other hand, the fact that one resource is seized and the other is not, is a bug in my opinion, and has no simple fix, I told AnyLogic but they didn't accept it as a bug... What I did in previous model was a very complicated set of rules to make it work,

Comment: It does seem like a bug, a pretty bad one for DES. Seems like this should be done manually with a wait block that frees agents when the "resources" (now just agents) are available. This will require reservation as of these agents as well. Kind of like recreating the resource pool concept manually. Thank you for your insights!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the condition is only checked once. There is no intelligence where agents ask again, this is your responsibility as a modeller.

Therefore, it is typically more elegant to specify the condition in a `Seize` block ("customize resource choice"). Here, the agent *will* notice if a resource unit becomes available and you do not end up with an infinite queue:
[image]

Comment: The customize resource choice in the seize block is great, but it gets tricky when you have a resource set being seized and you have conditions for multiple resources. Let's say you have a set of 3 different resource types and you have a condition for each of these three types, does this solution still work? I could not find a straightforward way to do it... That is why I opted for the conditions in the resource pool blocks.

Comment: see other reply

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the ResourcePool condition, maybe outsource it to a function and check that function *before* even seizing. If it cannot be satisfied, put agents into a queue (or Wait) and make them re-check manually in regular intervals.